# facebook share photo dialog cancel uploading callback android

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am using FacebookDialog.PhotoShareDialogBuilder for share  photo , its works fine, but after post , photo upload notification is shown , if any user cancelled uploading on tap  notification then how to get callback for this , Is that any way to get handle this